# Bring To A Settlement

Tags: phrasal-verbs

According to definition of 4 of this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/bring), "bring to" should only apply to a state, place, or condition.  But in this [example](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/news/9082870/Premier-League-sides-forced-to-pay-back-millions-of-pounds-in-tax-after-crackdown-on-image-rights-deals.html):

> The league agreed to mediate, helping ***bring*** as many as 15 clubs ***to a settlement*** with HMRC.

, a "settlement" is not a state, place, or condition.  Could the example be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a **bring to** phrase, because if you leave out *as many as 15 clubs*, then

> **helping bring to a settlement with HMRC.**

does not make any sense.

It is more likely sense 3 in your dictionary link:

> 3 
>   : to cause (something) to exist, happen, or start

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work isn't necessarily because it's not phrasal, though. _bring_ has an obligatory object (ie: it is transitive), so you need to always _bring __something___.

Answer (score 0):

A settlement indicagtes a condition of [some conflict] being settled.

This parallels the linked site's example, "bring water to a boil", in which the condition is expressed in the form of a noun.

Comment: A settlement is an agreement, not a condition.